# Invoking a Java program in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to java. i'm trying to invoke a java function on a `jsp` page.The function is supposed to copy a file from one directory to another directory. Through the `Jsp` I have to browse ahd select a file.. after this,i have to click on run button then it should perform the operation I gave in the java program. How to call this java program in `jsp`..please help me..
Java Code:

```
package copy;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class CopyDirectoryExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        File srcFolder = new File("D:\\CETAF");
        File destFolder = new File("C:\\ExecFolder");

         //make sure source exists
        if(!srcFolder.exists()){
            System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
            //just exit
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            try {
                copyFolder(srcFolder,destFolder);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //error, just exit
                System.exit(0);
           }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
        if(src.isDirectory()) {

            //if directory not exists, create it
            if(!dest.exists()){
               dest.mkdir();
               System.out.println("Directory copied from " 
                              + src + "  to " + dest);
            }

            //list all the directory contents
            String files[] = src.list();

            for (String file : files) {
               //construct the src and dest file structure
               File srcFile = new File(src, file);
               File destFile = new File(dest, file);
               //recursive copy
               copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
            }
        } else {
            //if file, then copy it
            //Use bytes stream to support all file types
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest); 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);
        }
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01                       Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
       <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Display file upload form to the user</TITLE> 
</HEAD>
<BODY>
 <FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="upload.jsp" METHOD=POST>
<br>
<br>
<br>
          <center>
                <table border="0" >     
                <tr>         
           <center>            
           <td colspan="2" align="center"><B>UPLOAD THE FILE</B>  
          <center>          
            </td>      
            </tr>      
            <tr>           
             <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
                 </tr>     
             <tr>          
          <td><b>Choose the file To Upload:</b></td>          
            <td><INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file"></td>
                  </tr>    
                 <tr>           
              <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
                 </tr>     
               <tr>           
                   <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"
              value="RUN"></td>
                  </tr>    
                  </table>       
                          </center>       
                       </FORM>
                       </BODY>
              </HTML>
```

Upload.jsp

```
                  <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
                 <%      String saveFile = "";   
                        String contentType = request.getContentType();  
                  if ((contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf
                        ("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {            
               DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());     
                 int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();        
                    byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];       
                         int byteRead = 0;        
                    int totalBytesRead = 0;       
                while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {       
                 byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);            
              totalBytesRead += byteRead;           
                  }           
                   String file = new String(dataBytes);        
                         saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);       
                           saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf           ("\n"));           
                     saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")                           +1,saveFile.indexOf                    ("\""));       
                int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");           
                    String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex+ 1,                         contentType.length());          
                      int pos;           
                   pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");           
             pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;         
               pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;          
                  pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;          
            int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;     
               int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;          
             int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;          
               saveFile = "D:/CETAF/Configuration/" + saveFile;         
                   File ff = new File(saveFile);          
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);          
                    fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));           
          fileOut.flush();            
                            fileOut.close();%><Br><table border="2">
                <tr>         
                         <td><b>You have successfully upload the file by the name of:</b>         
                          <%                  
                       out.println(saveFile);                 
                     }        
                              %>          
                          </td>      
                          </tr>
                         </table>
```

The above two are my jsp files...if i click on run button,it should call that java file and perform dat action..how to call that java file??

Comment: You just submit your form with html , where giving action as this servlet mapping.

Comment: how to map..can u explain it clearly?

Comment: @user3148359, it means you make the action's attribute maps to the appropriate servlet, someting like this: `<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="CopyDirectoryExample" METHOD=POST>`, with transforming the java class program as a servlet with implementing `doPost()` and removing `main()` function and `upload.jsp` file.

Comment: @Omar,Do i need to make any changes in CopyDirectoryExample java program??

Comment: Never call `System.exit()` if there is even the slightest chance your code will be invoked in an application server, and it's bad idea in most other contexts as well. It will shut down the entire JVM, including your server.